# mysql inside a docker container says "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' "

Tags: mysql, docker

### Dockerfile

I am trying to play with Docker. This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:latest
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD 123
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE users
ENV MYSQL_USER admin
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD 1234
ADD setup.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
EXPOSE 3306
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

### Access Mysql from container

And the following is my attempt to access to mysql from the container.

> root@76757566f93a:/# mysql -uroot -p123 mysql: [Warning] Using a
>   password on the command line interface can be insecure. ERROR 2002
>   (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

### Makefile

Finally, .. this is a Makefile I use to run all docker commands:

```
container = db
image-name = senso

run:
    docker run --name $(container) -d $(image-name)

bash:
    docker exec -it $(container) /bin/bash

build:
    docker build -t $(image-name) .
```

### mysql -v

I've also tried to run `mysql -v` to check if mysql is ok inside the container and I think is not.

> root@76757566f93a:/# mysql -v ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to
>   local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is `mysql` process is not running, as you override the `CMD` in your Dockerfile, as the base `CMD` starting `Mysql` process.

```
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

Remove the `CMD` from the Dockerfile.

You do not need to replace as the base image will do care of it, but if want to replace then use the following

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

Also `ADD setup.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` only possible when MySQL process is running with offical entrypoint script.